# Highlight field which failed validation

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using C# with MVC(Razor View Engine)

I'm doing validation using Annotation Like this:-

Model :-

```
[Required]
public int VendorId { get; set; }
```

Razor view Engine :-

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <label>@Html.LabelFor(r => Model.VendorId)</label>
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.VendorId, new SelectList(suppliers, "Value""Text"),"-Select-", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "select-full" })

 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.VendorId, null, new { style = "color: red" })
</div>
```

and it was showing error message

> The Vendor field is required.

if I'm not selecting vendor.

Now I want to highlight (Border Color in Red) of this Dropdown Field
instead showing this message if validation failed (DataAnnotation) instead showing a message on both client & server side

Answer (score 0):

You can check validate form, if form is invalid, just add:

```
$('#VendorId').attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:#FF0000 1px solid;");
```